# Outlook add-in B2C login popup can't communicate with the host add-in iframe

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, azure-ad-b2c, adal.js

I am using Adal.js from Microsoft to handle my Azure AD B2C login. The app doesn't automatically redirect the user to the B2C login page. So I have temporarily added popup:true option in AuthenticationContext and a login button for the users to click and activate the login. How can I get Adal.js to automatically redirect the users to the B2C login page when the add-in loads? I can get this to work for Excel and Word add-ins in the desktop, but not for the Outlook 365 add-in in the web browser.

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get Adal.js to automatically redirect the users to the B2C login page when the add-in loads?

If you want the add-in to popup the login page automatically, you just need to call the login function in the Angular controller. If the popup window is not popup, please ensure that the web browser allow the popups for the web sites. For example, we can enable it for Chrome via Settings-> Privicy-> Content-Pop-ups.